# JAVA Checking 10th place in a 2d Arraylist

Tags: java, arraylist

I want to check if the last numbers in an arraylist are a 10.My data is in a 2d arraylist with 110 elements every 10 numbers is one node, I want to verify that the last digit of each node is a 10.

example:
1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10  in this case its true
1,12,3,4,8,5,4,8,9,8  in this case its false

```
public static void main(String[]args){
   ArrayList<ArrayList<Double> > array= new ArrayList<ArrayList<Double> >();
    for (int i = 0; i < array.size(); i++){
        if(logic here){
            System.out.println(not 10.0);
        }else{
            system.out.pritnln(10.0);
        }
    }
}
```

how can I implement the correct logic for this case? Thank you!!!

Comment: What have you tried so far?  Do you know how to access a particular position in an array?  Do you know that a 2D array is an array of arrays?

Comment: yes, and i tried if(i%10=10) but it did not work.

Comment: % is the modulus operator - that code is going to check whether i (your loop counter) divided by 10 has a a remainder of 10.  That will not work. Break the problem down into steps - first, you want the ArrayList in position i - so array.get(i).  Then, you want to check the 10th element in the resulting array.  Does that make sense?

Comment: yes, I understand thank you

Answer (score 0):

We start count form 0
if(array.get(array.size()-1) == 10 -> this will return true if last index of array equals 10; you dont need for loop in this case.